# Load WordPress functions outside WordPress files in Add on Domain

Tags: outside-wordpress

I'm unable to load `wp-load.php` file from wordpress in my ADD ON DOMAIN. I am using `require_once('./wp-load.php');` to load `wp-load.php` and `get_header();` to load header in my php file. Primary Domain is loading wordpress functions fine but add domain is not, it is not throwing up any error.

```
<?php require_once("../wp-load.php"); ?>
```

I am expecting to load wordpress function in my php file on Add domain like the way Primary domain loads

Comment: How is your folder structure and how do you point your DOMAIN and ADD ON DOMAIN to?

Comment: public_html>`primarydomain` files >addon domain folder(inside the primarydomain there is my addon domain folder).

Comment: i pointed *add on domain* inside *primary domain*

Comment: I have install wordpress on both domain

Comment: any idea on how to solve this problem?

Comment: Welcome to [wordpress.se]. I hope you find the answer(s) you are looking for. Our site is different from most - if you have not done so yet, consider checking out the [tour](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tour) and [help center](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help) to find out how things work.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, the problem was a wordpress theme. I discover that some themes does not allow anyone to utilize wordpress functions like loading `wp-load.php` file from wordpress. Thanks to all who commented.